# Is it possible to successfully run "DJI GO4" or "UgCS for DJI" on Odroid C2?

Tags: android, arm, dji-sdk, odroid

I am building a ground station for planning the UAV missions. I have a computer with UgCS software, and I need SBC with a touchscreen and running "DJI Go4" and "UgCS for DJI" applications.
Both applications I try run on Odroid C2 with Android Marshmallow (6.0.1).
Unfortunately, the application does not detect UAV.
I am looking for a solution to run UgCS and DJI GO4 on any SBC. Has anyone checked or knows how to do it?

I have installed Android for Odroid C2 with Google Play. Applications is running but not detected UAV controller. I try with DJi Mavic2Pro and DJI Phantom3 Pro. In both cases there is no connection with the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this post in the odroid forum: https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=35695

With our ODROID N2 its working.